# What is value-result parameter passing?

Tags: java

I have a question regarding value-result.

http://euclid.cs.qc.cuny.edu/13-page-handout.pdf

On the first page, example 1 and 2, how does value-result and value-result(Algol W) work?

Comment: Please post the relevant code from the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know what book this is referring to, but the two flavors of call by value-result should be explained in:

> *"Sec. 5.2 on pp. 155 – 160 and the discussion of call-by-name on p. 165 in Sethi."*

There is a small section on "call by value-result" on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_value-result#Call_by_copy-restore), though they call it something else, and the definition could be different to the one used in the (unnamed) text book you are supposed to be using.

(One of the aims of this exercise is, I think, is to get *you* to read and understand these assigned sections of the textbook.)

Answer (score 0):

It's the result of running the code. Algol W is another programming language. There are samples of the results below the cod blocks in that PDF.

Comment: Huh?? - "call by value-result" is a method of parameter passing.